# Trying to create a simple Dictionary type application

Tags: python, oop, object

I'm trying to create a simple program to collect words and their translations, and then reiterate them in a different order. Honestly, I think the second part I can do no problem, but I'm not very well versed in use of objects in programming. Anyway, here's my code:

```
 def trial2():
    class ind:
        pass

    entry = raw_input('Please enter English, Spanish, POS. ')
    entry = entry.split(', ')
    ind.english = entry[0]
    ind.spanish = entry[1]
    ind.pos = entry[2]
    print ind()
```

Now, I'm not exactly sure what the best approach would be. I wouldn't think I would have an individual object for each entry (representing its English form, its Translation, and Part of Speech), but an iteration of one (?).

I've been looking around and doing a lot of reading on OOP, but I'm still just a little lost.

Comment: If you don't understand objects, why use them? Why not a simple tuple, or perhaps a namedtuple?

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary objects are probably going to be easier to work with than classes here:

```
def trial2():
    entry = raw_input('Please enter English, Spanish, POS. ').split(', ')
    word = {
        'english': entry[0],
        'spanish': entry[1],
        'pos': entry[2]
    }

    print word
```

My general rule of thumb is that if you define less than two methods on a class, it shouldn't be a class.

Comment: That seems to work a ton better, thanks so much--so extending off of this, I assume I can sort all of the dictionary items by various qualifiers (Sort by POS, for example). Additionally, any advice on how I would have multiple entries? (Ex. I need 400 words each with attributes of english, spanish, and pos--Append each dictionary instance of 'word' to an "ultimate" list and then sort/manipulate that?)

Comment: to @user1763569 : I suggest also when you're starting out programming not to reuse variable names if the type of object stored changes.  So if `entry = raw_input()`, then don't write `entry = entry.split()` -- being weakly typed, Python lets you do this, but I find that most of my students' coding problems come from reusing variable names in this way.  Call it `entryList = entry.split()` or something of that sort.

Comment: I would start with that. You can use `words.sort(key=lambda word: word['english'])` to sort `words` in-place by the words' english translations.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much everyone! I've looked at code for a long time, but am just now beginning to write things without a tutorial! =P Thanks for the help!